# How to prefix column names of data.frame which are !%in% list with dplyr::rename?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyselect

I have a list of column names which I do NOT want to change  `colsNotRename`.
All the other columns I do want to prefix. A way to do it in BaseR would be e.g.:

```
xx <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 3:5, Unknown = c("A","B","C"))
colsNotRename <- c("A","B")
cols <- !colnames(xx) %in% colsNotRename
colnames(xx)[cols] <- paste0("unknown.", colnames(xx)[cols])
```

or :

```
xx <- setNames(xx, c(colnames(xx)[!cols] , paste0("unknown.", colnames(xx)[cols])))
```

I am looking for an solution to this problem with dplyr::rename_

Answer (score 0):

Use `rename_at` with `setdiff(colnames(xx),colsNotRename)` or `-colsNotRename`

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>% rename_at(vars(-colsNotRename), ~paste0('unknown.',.))
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution with rename_if

```
library(dplyr)
xx %>% dplyr::rename_if(!names(.) %in% colsNotRename, ~paste0("unknown.", .))
```